# Bootstrap not loading in blade language

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

currently I'm learning laravel 5.1, and i'm making a simple forum like website. but first m stuck in register view, i have used blade language and it is not loading bootstrap library properly.

This is my main page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title></title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


  </head>

  <body>

    @yield('page-content')

     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my nav.blade.php

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://localhost/laravel/laravel/public">Ask UMT</a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

              <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Log In</a></li>
              <li>{!!link_to_route('get_register','Register')!!}</li>

            </ul>

          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->

      </nav>
```

And register.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.masters.main')

@section('page-content')



    @include('layouts.partials.nav')

      {!! Form::open(['route' => 'post_register','id' => 'registration-form']) !!}

        {!! Form::label('name','Full Name') !!}
        {!! Form::text('name',null,['id' => 'name','class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'Full Name','required'])!!}

        {!! Form::label('email','Email Address') !!}
        {!! Form::email('email',null,['id' => 'email','class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'Email Address','required'])!!}

        {!! Form::label('password','Password') !!}
        {!! Form::password('password',['id' => 'password','class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => 'Password','required'])!!}

        {!! Form::button('Register',['class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block','type' => 'submit'])!!}

     {!! Form::close() !!}



@stop
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the path to your `bootstrap.min.css` file is wrong. If you use the path `css/bootstrap.min.css`, the file should be placed in `public/css/bootstrap.min.css`.

All files that you want to access from the clientside should be placed in the `public` folder.

Furthermore you should use the `asset()` helper function, which will determine the right absolute path for you:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

--

The same is true for your `bootstrap.min.js` file.

Comment: The problem is in blade language but i cant figure it out

Comment: Is your page displayed correctly expect bootstrap is not loading? Are there any other errors?

Answer (score 1):

need to upload the files with the `asset()` function, so you specific to your project files will bring them to the public folder, thus leaving `{{asset ('css/bootstrap.css')}}`,

You can learn more [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-asset)

you need to use this method with css and js like this:

```
<link href="{{ asset('your-route/css/bootstrap.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

and

```
<script src="{{ asset('your-route/js/bootstrap.js') }}"></script>
```

I hope it helps you...